# Convert Uploaded S3 Images to Original File Path

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-s3

I attempted to move over our local WordPress images to S3 using the WP Offload S3 plugin and it turns out because the Object Versioning option was turned on, it added numbered folders for each image in the path, i.e:

```
[…]xxx.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/xxxxxxxx/example.jpg
[…]xxx.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/xxxxxxxx/example-123×456.jng
```

The original path was previously:

```
[…]xxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/example.jpg
[…]xxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/example-123×456.jng
```

If I delete the WP Offload S3 plugin and then reinstall it, it seems like the plugin's settings are still saved and the media still points to the Amazon S3 link, probably saved somewhere in the SQL database.

Is there a simple PHP script to convert the object-versioned file paths back to the original path on all of the already uploaded media?

I don't know much about coding, but perhaps something like this might be of reference? https://gist.github.com/TJNevis/8df059e8ba6d9cf28a01#file-s3fixexistingmedia-php-L27